# Load model asynchronously with a non-crud action

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js

I have an Ember 1.13 application and I want to list all users that match with another user. I have `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1/matches` that returns

```
 {"users":[{"id":1,"email":"test@test.com","nickname":"Test","bio":"test","created_at":"2015-06-28T16:03:52.423Z","updated_at":"2015-06-28T16:03:52.423Z","encrypted_password":"$2a$10$RPJmVJNfFvjwzIG0wfC6yONRz20WBogUw35ibz2Hv.M6TC/M7FZ8e","confirmation_token":null,"remember_token":"fb5653e22ad30d3ad3a90ab0b028bd7348cd71a1"}]}
```

As shown in [the doc](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/), I have this route :

```
export default Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1/matches')
```

And this template :

```
{{#each model as |user|}}
  user
{{/each}}
```

I should see `user` in my template but I have nothing. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{#each model.users as |user|}}
  user
{{/each}}
```